# NERDTree command automatically change directory and root directory

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Is it possible that whenever I select a directory and enter that directory from the NERDTree it should become the root directory? That is, every time I select a new directory the following two commands will be triggered: `cd` and :`NERDTreeCWD`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

set in your vimrc: `let g:NERDTreeChDirMode = 2`

Comment: you're my hero.

Comment: This answer is a diamond. Shine and value! Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: `cd` `CD` sequence  does about the same. Pros: it's blazingly fast - no lags in comparison to `C` Cons: longer to type

Answer (score 6):

The NERDTree provides two mappings you could use manually to get this effect: Typing `cd` on a node changes the directory to it, and typing `C` on a node, "enters" it via the NERDTree.

Personally, I often combine them -- just type `Ccd` -- the `C` will enter the directory and leave the cursor on it, and a `cd` will change the working directory to it.

Now, if you do want to create just one mapping to use directly, you could use the NERDTree's extension mechanism. Read up on `:help NERDTreeAPI` for the details, but the short version is: put a file in `~/.vim/nerdtree_plugin/cd_mapping.vim` with the following contents:

```
call NERDTreeAddKeyMap({
            \ 'key':           '_C',
            \ 'callback':      'NERDTreeEnterDirectoryAndCD',
            \ 'quickhelpText': 'Enter directory and cd into it' })

function! NERDTreeEnterDirectoryAndCD()
  let node = g:NERDTreeDirNode.GetSelected()

  exec 'cd ' . node.path.str({'format': 'Cd'})
  NERDTreeCWD
endfunction
```

This should do the trick with the keybinding `_C`. Change the `key` property to whatever you'd like the key to be.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! That's awesome! However, there is a problem when trying to hit the parent directory: E716 Key not present in Dictionary: path.str({'format': 'Cd'}) E15: Invalid expression: 'cd ' . node.path.str({'format': 'Cd'})

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. Is it possible you have an older version of the NERDTree? Could you check if you've got the master version installed locally?

Comment: you save my day

Answer (score 2):

`cd` `CD` ( *cd* -> changes pwd/cwd and *CD* -> sets tree root to pwd/cwd)